# __isset not returning correct result

Tags: php, magic-methods

Im trying to kinda link objects together using the magic php functions.

I have an abstract class called page, and every page in my website extends this class.
In this abstract class constructor i try to get a user object like this:

```
public function __construct(  ){        

    $user = new user();
    $this->user = $user->getIdentity();

    $this->getHeader();
    $this->switchAction(  );
    $this->getFooter();

}
```

Now in my pages i can use $this->user and it works all fine. Gives me back the user object if the user is logged in.
In my user class, i have a magic __get & __isset function :

```
 public function __get ( $name ){        
            switch ($name){
            case 'oAlbums':
                 return $this->oAlbums = album::get_ar_obj($arWhere = array('user_id' => $this->id) );
            break;

   public function __isset ( $name ){
        switch($name){
            case 'oAlbums':
                echo 'magic isset called, trying to call '. $name . '<br />';
                return isset($this->$name);
            break; 
        }       
    }
```

So when in a page, i want to check if a user has any albums at all by calling `$this->user->oAlbums` .
This returns an array with all the album objects, as expected. But when i do

```
if(empty( $this->user->oAlbums ))
    echo 'still give smepty';
```

in my page, it still echo's the string out..

Why is the __isset function not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__isset` should return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. TRUE if the variable exists **and has a value** and FALSE otherwise. You are actually returning the values of `$this->name`. You should just return `is_null($this->name)`. Change your code to:

```
public function __get ( $name ){        
    switch ($name){
        case 'oAlbums':
             return $this->oAlbums = album::get_ar_obj($arWhere = array('user_id' => $this->id) );
        break;
    }
}

public function __isset ( $name ){
    switch($name){
       case 'oAlbums':
            echo 'magic isset called, trying to call '. $name . '<br />';
            return !is_null($this->$name);
            break;

       default:
           return FALSE;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->oAlbums` is not yet set before you `__get()` it probably? Try:

```
$something = $this->user->oAlbums;
if(empty($this->user->oAlbums)) ...
```

... and it probably tells something different. Your `__isset()` should in my opinion just return `true`, making `empty()` actually `__get()` the value. Consider this difference:

```
<?php

class foo {
        function __get($name){
                return $this->$name = range(1,3);
        }
        function __isset($name){
                return isset($this->$name);
        }
}

class bar {
        protected $whatever = array();
        function __get($name){
                return $this->$name = range(1,3);
        }
        function __isset($name){
                return isset($this->$name);
        }
}
class foz {
        function __get($name){
                return $this->$name = range(1,3);
        }
        function __isset($name){
                return true;
        }
}

$foo = new foo();
var_dump(empty($foo->whatever));//true
$void = $foo->whatever;
var_dump(empty($foo->whatever));//false

$bar = new bar();
var_dump(empty($bar->whatever));//false

$foz = new foz();
var_dump(empty($foz->whatever));//false
```